# Generating "downloadable" binary data on client in say JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Disclaimer**: I haven't done web programming for ages and am not even sure what or where to search.

**Intro**

Everyone's familiar with the concept of downloading files from websites, you click a link on a webpage, the server gets the request containing the URL and responds with the file data appropriately packaged with the content type indicated and all.

**Problem**

Now, I'd like the same experience, except the data is generated fully on the client side without any requests going back to the server. I know I can generate all the data on client and even dynamically change the viewed page using DOM. But I'm not sure about embedding this data on the page in a downloadable way, whether it's possible at all and how to do it. Is it possible? In e.g. HTML+JavaScript? If it is, will it work in the major browsers such as IE, FF and Chrome? Will it need HTML5? Or am I doomed to serving the data from the server or using other technologies (maybe Flash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base64 encode the content into an the `href` attribute of an anchor `a` tag.  See:

http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/08/html5-how-to-create-downloads-on-fly.html